# Heap full of com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, c3p0

I'm analyzing a heap dump where I have 50% live set in the heap. This is  caused by a large amount of heap reserved just to hold all the `JDBC4Connection` and it's internal properties hashmap. This is a heapdump of an application running for a couple of days.

[image]

It looks like it's holding thousands of JDBC connection objects and it's configuration.

[image]

I found a question which asked a similar question, but got dismissed suggesting that the user was not closing connections: [Too many instances of "com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690525/too-many-instances-of-com-mysql-jdbc-jdbc4connection)

However, I'm using the `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor.findAll`, without querying the database directly. Code:

```
Specification<AccountProfile> spec = getUserInfoListSurfacing(userInfo);
JPAImpl.findAll(spec, new PageRequest(0, 1, Sort.Direction.DESC, "reportedDate")).getContent()
```

Here is the bean definition for this connection pool

```
<bean id="db" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="dataSourceName" value="users"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="${userdb.driver}"/>
        <property name="forceUseNamedDriverClass" value="true"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${userdb.url}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${userdb.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${userdb.password}"/>
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${userdb.hibernate.c3p0.initialPoolSize}"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${userdb.hibernate.c3p0.max_size}"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${userdb.hibernate.c3p0.min_size}"/>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${userdb.hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}"/>
        <property name="maxStatements" value="${userdb.hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${userdb.hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}"/>
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="${userdb.hibernate.c3p0.validationQuery}"/>
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="${userdb.hibernate.c3p0.testOnBorrow}"/>
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${userdb.hibernate.c3p0.acquireincrement}"/>
        <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout"
                  value="${userdb.hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout}"/>
        <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="${userdb.hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces}"/>
        <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="${userdb.hibernate.c3p0.maxconnectionage}"/>
        <property name="numHelperThreads" value="${userdb.hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads}"/>
        <property name="connectionCustomizerClassName" value="${userdb.hibernate.c3p0.connectionCustomizerClassName}"/>
    </bean>
```

I have not been able to find confirmed reports of memory leaks in the Hibernate versions that I'm using.

I'm using `spring-data-jpa` version 2.0.6.Final
`hibernate-core` version 4.3.5.Final
`hibernate-jpa-2.1-api` version 1.0.2.Final

Comment: c3p0 creates a pool of database connections. No wonder you are seeing lots of connection objects.

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman It creates a pool of 200 connections, not 45 thousand. The expectation is the JDBC connection will not be referenced once it's dropped by the pool.

Comment: I see your point.

Comment: Are you creating new application contexts to obtain a connection? (I.e. are you doing things like `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` in your code? Next to that you are probably loading your whole application twice (show your `web.xml`) and do you really need 200 connections? Finally I suggest to ditch C3P0 and replace it with [HikariCP](https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) (C3P0 isn't really maintained anymore).

Answer (score 1):

You show 224 instances of the object "managed". There is one instance of "managed" per Connection pool, so you have 224 Connection pools holding references to Connections, not just one. You have to understand why you are instantiating so many pools when a typical application just wants one.

The usual error that could cause this is to create a new Connection pool every time you mean to establish a new Connection. The less common cause is using the same DataSource to establish Connections under multiple authentications using dataSource.getConnection( user, password ). A new Connection pool is established for each distinct authentication.

Since you are not directly instantiating your Connection pool but using Spring to do it, it's not so easy to debug how why you are instantiating so any pools. One thing you should definitely add is a `destroy-method` attribute to your `bean` XML tag. That is...

```
<bean id="db" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
   ...
</bean>
```

You could be generating all these pools just by hot redeploying your app a lot, and failing to cleanup the old pools because Spring doesn't know it has to clean up your beans. See Spring's [Destruction Callbacks](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-disposablebean).

Comment: The `close` method is automatically detect as a destroy method (as of Spring 3.2). So depending on the version that might not be needed.